# Elasticsearch. Search data by current month

Tags: elasticsearch

I have next body

```
body = {
                "size": 100,
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "filter": [
                        {
                          "term": {
                            "some_id_1": some_id_1
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "term": {
                            "some_id_2": some_id_2
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "term": {
                            "some_id_2": some_id_2
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "terms": {
                            "some_strings": "a,b,c"
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "term": {
                              "created_at": dt.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
```

This will search all record by condition in term for dt.now().

Question: How i can search all documents for current month?

Will be grateful for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`range` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) instead with some [date math](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#date-math), like this:

```
{
   "range": {
      "created_at": {
        "gte": "now/M"
      }
   }
}
```

All documents whose `created_at` field is on the first day of this month or later will be returned.